# compiling rtmpdump for arm

Tags: linux, compilation, openssl, arm, rtmp

I am trying to compile rtmpdump (http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) for Qnap NAS 419p (arm)

I am not very exprenced with linux or compilation but am trying to learn.

make is complaining that it cant find openssl and im not sure where to start?

```
[/share/Qdownload/src] # ipkg install openssl
Package openssl (0.9.8v-2) installed in root is up to date.
Nothing to be done
Successfully terminated.
```

confirms that i have installed openssl

```
[/share/Qdownload/src] #
[/share/Qdownload/src] # ipkg install zlib
Package zlib (1.2.5-1) installed in root is up to date.
Nothing to be done
Successfully terminated.
[/share/Qdownload/src] #
```

confirms i have zlib the only other depenance i think i need.

```
[/share/Qdownload/src] # make linux
make[1]: Entering directory `/share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/src'
g++ -Wall   -O2   -c -o rtmp.o rtmp.cpp
In file included from rtmp.h:44,
             from rtmp.cpp:42:
dh.h:22:24: error: openssl/bn.h: No such file or directory
dh.h:23:24: error: openssl/dh.h: No such file or directory
dh.h:25:25: error: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory
dh.h:26:26: error: openssl/hmac.h: No such file or directory
dh.h:27:25: error: openssl/rc4.h: No such file or directory
In file included from rtmp.h:44,
                 from rtmp.cpp:42:
dh.h:34: error: 'BIGNUM' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:34: error: 'y' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:34: error: 'BIGNUM' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:34: error: 'p' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:34: error: 'BIGNUM' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:34: error: 'q' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:34: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
dh.h:35: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
dh.h:36: error: 'DH' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:36: error: 'dh' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:37: error: 'DH' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:37: error: 'dh' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:37: error: expected primary-expression before '*' token
dh.h:37: error: 'pubkey' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:37: error: expected primary-expression before 'nPubkeyLen'
dh.h:37: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
dh.h:38: error: 'DH' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:38: error: 'dh' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:38: error: expected primary-expression before '*' token
dh.h:38: error: 'privkey' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:38: error: expected primary-expression before 'nPrivkeyLen'
dh.h:38: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
dh.h:39: error: 'DH' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:39: error: 'dh' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:39: error: expected primary-expression before '*' token
dh.h:39: error: 'pubkey' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:39: error: expected primary-expression before 'nPubkeyLen'
dh.h:39: error: expected primary-expression before '*' token
dh.h:39: error: 'secret' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:39: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
dh.h:40: error: variable or field 'DHFree' declared void
dh.h:40: error: 'DH' was not declared in this scope
dh.h:40: error: 'dh' was not declared in this scope
In file included from rtmp.cpp:42:
rtmp.h:97: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'DH' with no type
rtmp.h:97: error: expected ';' before '*' token
rtmp.h:98: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'RC4_KEY' with no type
rtmp.h:98: error: expected ';' before '*' token
rtmp.h:99: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'RC4_KEY' with no type
rtmp.h:99: error: expected ';' before '*' token
rtmp.cpp: In member function 'int RTMP_LIB::CRTMP::ReadN(char*, int)':
rtmp.cpp:653: error: 'struct RTMP_LIB::LNK' has no member named 'rc4keyIn'
rtmp.cpp:654: error: 'struct RTMP_LIB::LNK' has no member named 'rc4keyIn'
rtmp.cpp:654: error: 'RC4' was not declared in this scope
rtmp.cpp: In member function 'bool RTMP_LIB::CRTMP::WriteN(const char*, int)':
rtmp.cpp:672: error: 'struct RTMP_LIB::LNK' has no member named 'rc4keyOut'
rtmp.cpp:674: error: 'struct RTMP_LIB::LNK' has no member named 'rc4keyOut'
rtmp.cpp:674: error: 'RC4' was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [rtmp.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/src'
make: *** [linux] Error 2
[/share/Qdownload/src] #
```

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: Was there a 'configure' step involved in this? It looks like the libraries are not in a place where compiler can find them so I bet it should be instructed with a path. Check the README how to achieve this.

Comment: Ah and one more thing. Have you checked if there is a openssl-devel or openssl-dev package available? The one you have installed is most likely only a library.

Comment: There is not a configure step, I don't have the dev version of open ssl. I will look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to install the development versions of the openssl and zlib packages.

Also make sure that openssl directory is somewhere in standard system include directories which should be `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include` and some others depending on your tool chain.

But don't take my word for it and execute `cpp -v < /dev/null`. It runs the GNU C Preprocessor with input from /dev/null. Should print the directory search paths. Look for "#include <...> search starts here:" followed by a list of standard include search paths. This is also the order of inclusion.

Comment: I don't have the development version of either package. unfortunately ipkg can only install the regular versions. I would have to compile the dev versions myself

Comment: I have many programs already dependant on openssl if i compile and install the dev version would i first need to remove the existing version, will it be ok to install both versions without breaking other things?

Comment: Not sure which distro you are on and to be honest I have never dealt with ipkg. Is it Slack? In my Debian/Ubuntu experience the -dev version does not remove a package but adds more files (includes, devs docs, etc.) so you can include/link the library properly.

Comment: I was mistaken i have been able to use ipkg to install the openssl-dev package, it just was not showing with "ipkg list". IPKG is Optware a lightweight package manager. The Qnap nas has no native package manger. Will let you know how it go's

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling for ARM it is not enough to install libraries for your own distro... you need libraries and a cross-compiler which runs on your development machine (probably x86 or x86_64) but generates code for the target platform (ARM).

If you don't have a cross-compiler for this Qnap NAS, [this link](http://wiki.qnap.com/w/index.php?title=User%3aAnthonyDoko&setlang=fi#Step_5%3a_Create_the_arm-eglibc-linux-gnueabi_cross_compiler_toolchain_with_crosstool-ng) should help you generate one with [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/), which is a great tool which helps you build cross-compilers from scratch. Then you will probably need a root filesystem with libraries made for your target platform too.

Everything involving cross-compiling is non-trivial, but we can try to help. What distro are you running on your machine?

Comment: Thank you for you offer of help. I am not attempting to cross compile but compile directly on the Qnap NAS. I have a compiler installed and Optware IPKG Package Manager, Unfortunately I cant get the openssl-dev package from ipkg. I am guessing it may be a much harder task than I anticipated to do this.

Comment: I don't know ipkg, but depending on your distro, the package is not called "-dev". Do you know which distro are you using? (Slackware I'm sure it is not.. for I use it everyday)